# label_image add screenshot to image_path

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, image-recognition

I need to add screenshot to the network instead of `image_path`

```
import os, sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

### take a screan shot
printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,800,800)))
imagescrean =  cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# change this as you see fit
##image_path = sys.argv[1]  ### change path to
image_path = imagescrean    ### screan shot

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()


# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

The problem is that

```
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
```

takes array of numbers and tells me

```
Expected binary or unicode string, got array([[[203, 186, 168],

[203, 186, 168],

[235, 230, 224],
```

Comment: Your image data is already in `imagescrean`, what are you trying to do by passing it as a file name. Pass it directly to the input tensor

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is, as the error says, passing an array instead of a path to the image. And this occurs because your screenshot is not saved so it does not have a path yet.

A simple solution would be to save the screenshot first and then pass that path.

```
cv2.imwrite("screenshot.jpg", imagescrean)
image_path = "screenshot.jpg"
```

This should work fine.